# Laravel: seeding tables other than Users

Tags: laravel, seeding

UPDATE: I am going to include my full file replacing the partial view I had. The seeder for the User table works, but the one for the Groups table does not. I do have those tables produced by Sentry but I only created a Model for Groups that has nothing in it other than the declaration of the class. Don't know what else to include.

```
<?php

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder {

    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Eloquent::unguard();

        //User::create(array('email' => 'foo@bar.com'));

        // $this->call('UserTableSeeder');

        $this->command->info('User table seeded!');
    }
    }


    class UserTableSeeder extends Seeder {

        public function run()
        {
             User::create(array(
                       'username' => 'alvaro',
                       'permissions' =>'{"user":1}'
                       ));

            $this->command->info('User table seeded!');
        }
    }   


    class GroupTableSeeder extends Seeder {

        public function run()
        {
             Group::create(array(
                       'name' => 'usuario',
                       'permissions' =>'{"user":1}'
                       ));

            $this->command->info('Group table seeded!');
        }
    }
```

But actually, the one I want is the Groups tables (I am on Sentry).  Yes, I have created the Model for Group, as Group.php but I don't know how to define its contents. Sometimes I have seen on other occasions that it suffices with just defining the class, but here I dont know, it doesn't work that easily.

Just doing something like

```
class GroupTableSeeder extends Seeder
```

will not work as it says that such class does not exist.

Comment: Did you make sure to run the Sentry migrations first? Command should be: `php artisan migrate --package=cartalyst/sentry`, which will create the `users`, `groups`, `throttle` and `users_groups` table in your database.

Comment: yes, I have all those tables. I ran everything using Syntara which includes sentry.

Comment: What happens if you uncomment the line which has `$this->call('UserTableSeeder')`?  Does that tell you class does not exist as well?

Comment: yes, when I run the GroupTableSeeder having uncommented the $this->call('UserTableSeeder') also repeats the same message

Comment: One posting elsewhere says it is necessary to use namespaced files like
: // database/seeds/UserTableSeeder.php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\User;

but I dont know how to apply that to Group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I needed to do was to create a separate file having that name GroupTableSeeder.php

and include the code in there. For some reason, while UserTableSeeder can be inside a file called DatabaseSeeder and it works, it does not work for other tables.

```
class GroupTableSeeder extends Seeder {

        public function run()
        {
             Group::create(array(
                       'name' => 'basicuser',
                       'permissions' =>'{"user.create" :-1,"user.delete" :-1,"user.view":1,"user.update":-1,"post.create":1}'
                       ));

            $this->command->info('Group table seeded!');
        }
    }
```

Comment: No one's going to downvote you for answering your own question. That's fine. In the future, try to provide code for everything you do, including answers, so others can see how you fixed it and learn from that. I was thinking maybe the issue was a folder/class structure issue, but you seem to have figured that out. Well done, and keep up the hard work.

Comment: I have included the code, it is the same that was above, only it had to go in a separate file.

Comment: Answering your own question was the right thing to do. Just don't forget to accept your own answer! (you'll have to wait 48 hours though) Also you can't go below 1 rep ;)